# Some questions on Schur's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I'm trying to learn the basics on representation theory for finite groups and I'm following [these notes](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Eccheng/Notes/RTnotes.pdf). Now, Theorem 1.8 (page 4), states the following Theorem (which is the so-called Schur's Lemma).

**Theorem 1.8:** If $V$ and $W$ are irreducible representations of $G$ and $\varphi: V \to W$ is a $G$-module homomorphism, then:

(i) either $\varphi$ is an isomorphism or $\varphi = 0$.

(ii) If $V = W$, then $\varphi = \lambda \cdot I$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, $I$ the identity map.

On page 8, however, the same Schur's Lemma is stated in a little alternative way, in order to get some corolaries of it. The author states that the Schur Lemma is:

**Theorem 2.5:** Let $\rho_{i}:G \to GL(V_{i})$ be two irreducible representations of the finite group $G$. Let $f: V_{1}\to V_{2}$ be a morphism of representations, i.e. $\rho_{2}(g)f(v_{1}) = f(\rho_{1}(g)v_{1})$ for all $g \in G$ and $v_{1}\in V_{1}$. Then:

(1) If $V_{1}$ is not isomorphic to $V_{2}$, then $f = 0$

(2) If $V_{1}$ is isomorphic to $V_{2}$, then $f$ is a scalar multiple of the identity.

**Question 1:** Okay, so I'm really confused about this second version of the Theorem. It really *seems* to be just rephrasing the first theorem, but I don't know for sure. First of all, $f$ in Theorem 2.5 is assumed to be a morphism, but not necessarily linear I guess. It is not clear to me if $f$ is the $\varphi$ of Theorem 1.8 or if its not. Also, it is not clear to me if by "$V_{1}$ is isomorphic to $V_{2}$" it means that these are isomorphic under $f$ or under $\varphi$. Of course that, if $f$ is the isomorphism between $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$, then $f$ is the $\varphi$ of Theorem 1.8 and the result is just a restatement, but it is not clear to me if this is the case.

After this, the author defines a new object:
$$f' = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G}\rho_{2}(g)^{-1}f\rho_{1}(g)$$
assuming $f$ is linear. He then wants to prove that if $V_{1}\cong V_{2}$, $f'$ is a homothety of ratiu $\frac{1}{\text{dim}V_{1}}Tr(f)$. And to do that he writes:
$$Tr(f') = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}Tr(\rho_{1}(g)^{-1}f\rho_{1}(g)) = Tr\lambda = \text{dim}V_{1}\cdot \lambda$$
where he used that $f$ is the isomorphism between $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ and, thus, $f = \lambda$.

**Question 2:** In the above identities, he used $\rho_{2}(g) = \rho_{1}(g)$. But why is that? Does it follow from $V_{1}\cong V_{2}$? In other words, if two vector spaces are isomorphic, their representations can be assumed to be *the same*?

Comment: You should perhaps have mentioned that both results refer to representations over ${\mathbb C}$. I am sure that a morphism of representations has to be a linear map. There is really very little difference between the two statements. The first part is in any case very easy. Thm 1.8 (i) follows from the fact that $\ker \phi$ and ${\mathrm im}(\phi)$ are both invariant under the action of $G$ (i.e. they arew subrepresentations/submodules of $V$ and $W$).

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks for the comment. The proof of Theorem 1.8 is indeed not difficult to understand. Actually, I'm okay with this theorem. What I don't understand is how Theorem 2.5 is just rephrasing Theorem 1.8. When the isomorphism is assumed, is it given by $f$? Or is it given by some other $\varphi$ and the conclusion $f = 0$ is a consequence of $\varphi = 0$?

Comment: For Question 1, the definition I learned goes as follows. Let $G$ be a group with representations $\rho_i : G \to \mathrm{GL}(V_i)$ on two vector spaces $V_1, V_2$ over a field $F$. A ***representation homomorphism*** $f : V_1 \to V_2$ is a linear transformation of $F$-vector spaces such that $g * f(v) = f( g * v)$ for all $v \in V_1$ and $g \in G$.

Comment: So, okay, $f$ in question 1 is linear but not necessarily an isomorphism. I believe Theorem 2.5 is simply saying "if $f$ is not an isomorphism, $f = 0$ and if it is, then $f= \lambda$", which is exactly Theorem 1.8. This makes sense, right?

Comment: Question 2 is not clear yet, tho.

Comment: For question (2): there is no identity map unless $V_1$ and $V_2$ are the same vector space. Even then, you can have equivalent aka isomorphic but *distinct* representations $\rho_1,\rho_2$ on the same vector space - in this case, nonzero scalar multiples of the identity are *not* equivariant aka intertwining aka $G$-linear. So the statement (and subsequently, the proof) of Theorem 2.5 (and Corollary 2.6) needs to fix part (2) by saying $V_1=V_2$ (that is, the same representation, not merely the same vector space, so maybe even write $\rho_1=\rho_2$ instead), not $V_1\cong V_2$. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I got it.

**Question 1:** $f$ here is a $G$-module homomorphism (which is, by definition linear) but not necessarily an isomorphism. Item (a) of Theorem 2.5 states that if $f$ is not invertible, then $f = 0$. Item (b) of this theorem states that if $f$ is an isomorphism (and as a consequence $\rho_{1}$ and $\rho_{2}$ are said to be isomorphic), then $f$ is a scalar multiple of the identity. So, Theorem 2.5 is just item (i) of Schur's Lemma restated indeed.

**Question 2:** For question 2, as runaway44 mentioned in the comments, it should state $V_{1} = V_{2}$ instead of $V_{1}\cong V_{2}$. But, more importantly, $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ are used in the notes (with abuse of notation) to indicate its underlying representations. So $V_{1} = V_{2}$ is not only an equality between vector spaces, but it also means $\rho_{1} = \rho_{2}$. This is why $\rho_{2}$ is taken to be $\rho_{1}$ in the formulas.